# Finding E[1/X] from E[X]

Tags: statistics

Is there a shortcut? 
I already have E[X] where X=Y+1, thus I can separate it into E[Y]+E[1], and for Y, it's number of tries is n, and the probability p.

Comment: There is no shortcut along the same lines

Comment: :3_\ have mercy on me, I'm only helping a friend

Comment: How about first doing something simpler?  Find $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln 2$ from $\int_1^2 x\,dx = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $X$ is nonzero, you should be able to apply the Law of the Unconscious Statistician to compute

$E[1/X] = \sum_j \frac{1}{x_j} p(x_j)$

or in the continuous case

$E[1/X] = \int \frac{1}{x} p(x) dx$.

Edit: it seems OP is looking for the case when Y~bino(n,p).  So from the definition and the law we have 
$E[1/X] = E[1/(Y+1)] = \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{j+1} p(n,j)$
where $p(n,j) = \binom{n}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$.  I'll leave the fun part of computing the sum up to OP!

Comment: Sorry what's p(x)?

Comment: @AltheaC the pdf, probability density function or pmf, the probability mass function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function

Comment: Sorry if I sound rude, but because I'm just helping a friend out, if my E[Y] is already np, and E[Y+1]=np+1, is there any way I can calculate E[1/Y+1] just like that?

Comment: Sure, so $Y$ is a binomial random variable, no?  I'll update my post in a moment.

Comment: binomial random variable = binomial distribution right?

Comment: @AltheaC yes, that is correct

Comment: @AltheaC, okay, updated my top level comment to clarify